# Error on jupyter when trying to make a request

Tags: python, jupyter

I´m trying to make a simple request on jupyter with the package requests but the console is giving me this error:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.amarillas.cl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /b/abarrotes/p-2/?tieneCobertura=true (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

This is a summary of my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

r = requests.session()
r2 = r.get("https://www.amarillas.cl/b/abarrotes/p-2/?tieneCobertura=true")
soup = bs(r2.text, 'lxml')
pub = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'titleFig'})
title = pub[0].find_all('span', {'class': 'semibold'})[1].text
print(title)
```

P.S.: I don't know if it’s important, but I'm working with an ec2 r5.2xlarge Amazon instance

Comment: Does your security group egress allow outgoing https connections?

Comment: I have been told that we allow outgoing connections

Comment: Are you able to run this code locally?